# What is the difference between specifying a class in these two ways?

Tags: java, android, android-2.2-froyo, android-sdk-2.3, android-sdk-2.1

I can run this code in my computer:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

inside `onResume()`. I sent the code to someone else for testing. But they tell me that that this line shows an error in their SDK, and replacing it with

```
getWindow().addFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

works, while in my case, both the codes work. Why is this happening?

PS: My SDK version is the one with the zip file name `adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522`. I am not sure the exact version they are using, but it is newer than mine.

Comment: using static values from instances could be the cause of problem for their compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`WindowManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.html) is a class in the Android SDK. Its fully qualified name is `android.view.WindowManager`. The `WindowManager.LayoutParams` is a nested class of `WindowsManager` and its fully qualified name is `android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams`

You can either specify the fully qualified name when you want to use it.

```
getWindow().addFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

or you can import its outer class

```
import android.view.WindowManager;
```

and use it directly

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: both of our codes are exactly the same, so how can I make it so that they don't have to add android.view ?

Comment: @user13267 Use the `import` statement before your class declaration.

Comment: `import android.view.WindowManager;` is present, otherwise it doesn't compile even on my SDK

Comment: @user13267 Can you please edit your question and add the code that doesn't compile and give us the compilation error?

Comment: I am sorry but the error occurs in the other person's computer and all they told me was that it doesn't compile unless we use `android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` inside `addFlags()'. In my case it works either way.

Comment: @user This depends on the error. Have they added the `import`? Is the Android SDK on the classpath?

Comment: the code file is exactly same as mine so they have the import as well, but I am not sure about the classpath. How can I check about the classpath on my computer?

Comment: @user13267 A classpath is different for every Java application and is set with the `-cp` flag. If you are using an IDE like eclipse you can check in the `Java Build Path` in the project properties.

Comment: I can see four tabs, Source, Project, Libraries and Order and Export. How do I check (in my computer) if Android SDK is on the classpath?

Comment: @user It would normally be under `Libraries` with a name like `Android SDK X`.

Comment: There are three options: Android 4.3, Android Dependencies and Android private libraries. Each is a tree root (that is, each has a + sign next to it), but I can't find anything of the format `Android SDK X` in any of the sub branches

Comment: @user No, what you have seems fine. Does the other computer also have that?

Comment: I am sorry but right now I cannot say what the computer might have at that place, but I am sure they are all left at the default values. Could this be the point that is causing the error at their computer but not at mine?

Comment: @user13267 I don't think so. If it was, putting the fully qualified name wouldn't work either. It's probably an error in the `import` statement. The compilation error will give you more details when you can get it.

Comment: ok if they provide me the compilation error I will post it here. Thank you very much for your help and time.

Comment: @user You're welcome. If you want you can post it here, but consider also posting a new question with all the relevant information if you find the question is unrelated to this one.